# How can I keep track of changes to a Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, logging

I am creating a website that will be used by an accounting dept. to track budget expenditures by different projects.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 for the database and ASP.net C# MVC 3 for the website.

What my boss has asked me to do is every time any user updates or creates a project, we need to log that change into a new table called `Mapping_log`. It should record the whole `Mapping` row being saved or created, and additionally the user and the datestamp. The notes field will now be mandatory, and the note should be saved to the `Mapping_log`.

Now when editing the PA, the Notes field will always be empty and below it, it should have a list of the older notes organized by date. I have been looking into maybe using Nlog and Log4net but I have not been able to find any good tutorials for a situation like mine. It seems that those modules are mostly used for error logging, which although important is not exactly what I am try to do at the moment.

I need some direction... does anyone have any advice or tutorials that I could use to learn how I can implement a process that will keep track of changes made to the data by users of the site.

Thanks for your help/advice!

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for a database trigger.

Comment: A database trigger may work like Josh said.  This sounds to me like a pretty straight forward requirement.  I'm not advocating reinventing the wheel but I feel trying to implement a third-party tool for this feature may be a bit of overkill.  Can you not just create the logging feature yourself?

Comment: Do you have to use another table? There is a very good solution for logging changes in the same table. You can add columns isDeleted, datestamp and username. When creating a row you will simply add it, but when updating you will mark the current one as deleted and add a new one. This way you will have a history of changes.

Comment: Which technology are you using for persistence? EF, NH, ADO...?

Comment: @DustyLau I probably could create the logging feature myself but I have never done anything like a logging feature before so I was looking for a guide that I could use as a base for the new feature. I agree though I don't want to use a third party tool if I don't have to!

Comment: @shizik I don't have to use another table that was just what my boss thought would be the best way to implement a solution. I am a new developer(I just graduated in December) so if you know of any tutorials I could use to use to help me start that would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider two new features that SQL Server 2008 introduced: [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You could use that and avoid your custom `Mapping_log` table.

But if you need to apply a more complex -business- rule, perhaps it will better doing that in the application layer, rather than purely in the database.

Regards.

Comment: Interesting article about change tracking but after turning change tracking on how do I use MVC 3 to display the changes in my Edit View? I am googling how to do this right now as well but I wanted to let you know that I have read your answer and I am working to understand if this solution will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I've known the existence of this features for a while, but I never had the chance to use it. For Change Data Capture, it seems you need to use a function named [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627(v=sql.105).aspx) (which is a table valued function). Maybe you can map the result into an EF entity, or create your own function that wraps the cdc one, and then map your custom function with EF.

Comment: I ended up doing it in the application layer like you suggested, I needed to keep track of changes with specific users and if I had tracked the changes through the database every log entry would have root as the user. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I would just create two triggers - one for the update, one for the insert.

These triggers would look something like this - assuming you also want to log the *operation* (insert vs. update) in your `Mapping_Log` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Mapping_Insert
ON dbo.Mapping
AFTER INSERT
AS
   INSERT INTO dbo.Mapping_Log(col1, col2, ..., colN, User, DateStamp, Operation)
      SELECT 
         col1, col2, ..., colN, SUSER_NAME(), GETDATE(), 'INSERT'
      FROM
         Inserted
```

(*your UPDATE trigger would be very similar - just replace "insert" by "update" wherever it appears*)

This is done "behind the scenes" for you - once in place, you don't have to do anything anymore to have these operations "logged" to your `Mapping_Log` table.